# What are instrumental variables really measuring?

Tags: regression, intuition, instrumental-variables

Alright, so  know what instrumental variables are and can do stuff with them, but I'm playing around with the math itself and I'm getting a little confused and would love some clarification.

I'll post up the relevant code for what I'm doing and insert some graphs to make it as clear as possible what I'm doing.

Let's define a covariance matrix

```
Sigma = np.array(
    [[ 1e5,  1e4, -1e3],
     [ 1e4,  5e3,  1e3],
     [-1e3,  1e3,  1e3]]
#       y     x1   x2
```

We see that there's a relationship between x1 and x2 and that both variables effect y. If we generate 100 observations that have this covariance matrix, we can run a regression of `y ~ x1` and `y ~ x1 + x2`. I call the former the "omitted variable bias" regression and the second the "true" regression. After running this experiment 100 times we end up with the following distribution

[image]

Now Let's say that instead of having x2 we now have u meaning it's unobervable. Luckily we also have an instrument z that covaries with x1 and with y but we believe it only covaries with y because of its relationship with x1. Our new data has the following covariance matrx

```
Sigma = np.array(
    [[ 1e5,  1e4,  -1e3, 1e3],
     [ 1e4,  5e3,   1e3, 1e3],
     [-1e3,  1e3,   1e3,   0],
     [ 1e3,  1e3,    0,  1e3]]
)  #    y     x1     u    z
```

If we then run a similar experiment as above. The the endogenous case is `y ~ x1` and then second is `y ~ [x1 ~ z]`. I call this "endog" and "iv" respectively.

[image]

We might have thought that we could expect our iv regression to approximate the "true" b1 from our first experiment, but it doesn't? Why?

I think it's because our "true" coefficient is a partialed out b1 and our other one isn't partialed out... If this is true, how do I calculate how much to partial out? (assuming I knew the covariance matrix which in practice, obviously can't happen)

I feel like this also highlights something that I haven't heard get brought up in the literature. It's like IV is talked about as a valid solution when you can't control for control for selection bias but that's not exactly what's going on... I think it's the unpartialed b1 coeficient that we can recover.

Anyways, that's the state of affairs for how I'm thinking about it right now. Insight to help correct what I'm not thinking about correctly and filling the gap would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but I can tell you that your setup is incorrect.  For Z to be a valid instrument it needs to be independent of both U and Y when conditioning on X.  That's not the case in the covariance matrix that you devised.

Comment: If you set the covariance of Z with Y to zero, the expected value of my B1 was 0. Which makes sense when you think of the formula cov(z,y) is in the numerator so I don’t think it makes sense to set it to 0

Comment: Zero covariance doesn't give the conditional independence you need.  It's the partial correlation that needs to be zero.

Comment: Ahhhh, that might be what I’m missing. Thank you!

Comment: It's much easier to do this simulation exercise if you simulate the data from the linear equations (with errors) whose coefficients IV is supposed to recover, rather than doing it from the a covariance matrix. The requirement that abstrusiosity mentioned is simply that the instrument shows up in the equation determining  x1, but not in the equation determining y. It affects y only through x1.